# Cron does not run in a PHP Docker container

Tags: php, docker, cron, dockerfile, containers

I am using the `php:7.4-fpm` Docker image and I'm trying to set up cron to run but it's not running.

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    graphviz \
    curl \
    supervisor

# Install Imagick
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && \
    pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl

# Permissions for Laravel
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www

# Copy crontab file to the cron.d directory
COPY ./docker/php-server/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

EXPOSE 9000

CMD bash -c "cron && php-fpm"
```

When I enter the container and check the contents of `/etc/cron.d/crontab` it is correct

```
* * * * * php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# An empty line
```

But it's not being run. I'm not sure what's going on here..

When I run `service cron status` it says `[ ok ] cron is running.` But nothing is happening.

Comment: Maybe copying the crontab in the Dockerfile changed the owner/group `/etc/cron.d/crontab`

Comment: Just a side note: instead of `apt-get install` and `docker-php-ext-install` what about using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally managed to solve it. I have no idea why COPYing the cron file wasn't working. I still don't know why. (maybe someone smarter than me can explain it). But I solved it very simply by appending my commands to the `/etc/crontab` file and now it works.

P.S. *crontab file requires a new line character at the end so using `echo` adds it automatically.*

**Here is my updated Dockerfile** (I deleted all the other lines where I copied the crontab):

```
RUN echo "* * * * * root php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, fixed by setting up the cron on the machine hosting the docker container instead of the container itself.

So the cron entry translates to something like :

`* * * * * docker exec web php artisan schedule:run >> storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1`

If you face an issue with tty allocation, try with `docker exec -it`

Comment: But I want to have cron running in my container. When I run `service cron status` it says `[ ok ] cron is running.` But nothing is happening.