# Laravel scheduler and docker cron

Tags: php, laravel, docker, cron

I have a docker file which has some of the following

```
ADD ./.docker/config/cron/$BUILD_ENV.cron /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
```

and the file ends with

```
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

My cron file comprises of

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/pub/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

With the extra line of course.

If I create the file with the following the cron runs.

```
 * * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

However  my laravel artisan isn't firing? Any help would be appreciated. The cron is created as root, and executed as root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron does not run in a PHP Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66010850/cron-does-not-run-in-a-php-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

**If you come here in 2023 with Laravel 8+ and Dockerfile :**

I spent also hours with running this Snippet from Laravels Documentation

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

in my Dockerfile.
(https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

First, make sure `cron` is installed in your VM. If not, install it:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
```

To check if installation was successful, simply check if binary can be found in VM:

```
which cron
```

If successful, `/usr/sbin/cron` could be displayed in the terminal.

For debugging purposes i create a logfile for the cronjobs output:

```
# Create the log file
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
```

Of course, you coulde also print the output to Docker by replacing `/var/log/cron.log` with `/dev/null 2>&1` or you could simply print to the Laravels logs (/storage/logs).

Next step in my solution is the actual definition of the crontab which will be calling the Laravel scheduler:

```
# Setup cron job
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * cd /app && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab
# Leave empty line #
```

`-l` flag shows current crontab.

Finally execute cron as CMD (and serve app):

```
CMD cron && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

I know, serving the app this way without reverse proxy is absolutely not recommended, especially for Production.